# Submodules generated by relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, free-modules

When definig the tensor product, the textbook says that:

The tensor product $M \otimes_RN$ is constructed as the quotient of the free module $R^{\oplus(M\times N)}$ modulo the submodule generated by the following elements, where $(m,n)$ stands for the standard basis element $e_{(m,n)}$:
$$(m+m',n) - (m,n) - (m',n)$$
$$(m, n+m') - (m,n) - (m,n')$$
$$(xm,n) - x(m,n)$$
$$(m,xn) - x(m,n)$$
for all $m,m'\in M$ and $n,n' \in N$ and $x\in R$.

The problem is that I do not really understand which or how are those elements and how do I need to understand the quotient. Can somebody give an explanation of how these quotient and elements work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what it is exactly that you are confused about. Do you understand the general concept of quotienting a module by a submodule? In the quotient, the part that was originally inside the submodule becomes trivial. The idea is to enforce bilinearity relations in the tensor product, e.g. $(m+m')\otimes n = m \otimes n + m' \otimes n$ exactly because we are annihilating the element $(m+m',n) - (m,n) - (m',n)$. And similarly for the other bilinearity relations.